# angular2 - hiding the row column using hidden

Tags: angular, angular2-template, hidden-field

I just want to hide the last column 'Id' of a row in a table depending on some condition if(colValue == "Id").

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let colValue of headerRow" [hidden]="colValue == Id">{{colValue}}</th>
</tr>
```

Below are the row columns.

No | Date | Name | Type | Status | Balance | Comments | Id |

I don't want to hide but want to hidden. How can i achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could create css style then binding class css to element

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

then in template:

```
<th [class.hide]="colValue == Id"></th>
```

avoid using `hidden` property, it maybe lead a bug when you bind to host. and `hidden` will add `display: none !important`.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

```
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let colValue of headerRow" *ngIf="colValue != Id">{{colValue}}</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: *ngIf will remove the last column from the DOM. But i want to hide.(HiddenField)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to create a table component. I would recommend not to do that. You might just end up with having a lot of gui releated code in the javascript instead of the html page. Can I ask why it needs to be hidden? Why is *ngIf not enough?

Comment: When i have more rows, if i click any of the row, i am getting the 'id' value that is stored in the last column of every table row. From that 'id' i will be displaying more results(like drill down).

Comment: You don't need to have it in a html element to do that: here is an example. '<tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-click="onRowClicked(row)">' and in the controller: '$scope.onRowClicked =function(row){var id=row.Id}'. Let the controller do the job